# Is it possible to deploy a dll straight to AWS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, deployment, visual-studio-2010

I am interested in running a server application on windows that has hot swappable libraries.  The server software is able to recognize when a new version of the dll has been deployed.  Right now I am running my server locally, but I am curious if it is possible to run a development environment on AWS and have a local copy of VS2010 deploy right to that server?

Comment: I would recommend against installing VS2010 on a virtual server in the cloud. You can do it for sure, there's no restriction. What is the problem with using your local computer for development?

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with using my local computer, but I was just curious if something like this would be possible.  I could just write a bash script to transfer the file after my build, but I feel like VS and its all in one solutions would have something for this.

Answer (score 1):

A virtual machine is just that, it's a fake machine running on another machine.  Anything you can do to a physical machine, you can do to a virtual machine.  Does this work on a physical machine?  If so, it should be possible on a virtual one.

Comment: I am more interested in deploying from my development machine to the server.  Right now, I can only build to my local drive.  I guess I could set up a network share to a location outside my local network, but that seems a bit overkill?